# Show Post Types customized in Template Page

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

My plugin has custom Post Types that open on a custom page triggered by the following hook:

`add_filter ('template_include', 'taxonomy_template'); // PRINTING PAGE`

however, this page only appears when I access the menu:

> Settings > Permanent Links

and saved without even changing anything, is there a hook that makes this check and saves automatically?

Comment: Filters generally don't print anything, they return. See [`template_include` examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: Yes, it returns correctly, but only without this change in the permanent links the page is not recognized

Comment: Can you please explain your problem better? What are you trying to achieve, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I have a template page to display data to be printed, this page for some reason did not appear without updating the wordpress settings manually, I researched and discovered that it has to do with the rewrite rules, I used flush_rewrite_rules (); and it worked

Comment: Expensive [flush_rewrite_rules()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) does what you are asking for. But it's unclear what do you want to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution found was to update the rewrite rules right after registering my new post type, using this code at the end of the function:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```